# What to do with black background color images

Tags: graphics, color

I have this image:

[image]

The black color is a problem for many reasons:

1. The majority of the figures have white color
2. Printing this black piece within the white document pages doesn't seem to be a good aesthetic idea

But if I remove the black color then the majority of this image text and some buttons disappears...

What to do? Make my own image? Focus on the circle?

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
      \caption{my caption}
      \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfigure.png}
        \label{fig:mifigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You coould invert all colours, like a negative.

Comment: The circle can be done using TikZ, the rest is simple text.

Comment: How can invert only the colors of this image?

Comment: I don't now. Gimp? Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is mostly text, I'd suggest you write everything in LaTeX and just keep the circle. You could even draw the circle in tikz if you're familiar with it.

To stray away from LaTeX, you could invert all colours (would give you a pale blue circle instead of orange), but any image manipulation program (Photoshop, GIMP...) would allow you to select the black area (with continuous selection tool, or however it is called) and fill it in white. Even simpler, you could use the elliptic selection tool to copy-paste you cricle wherever you want and/or delete the middle.